# Deserializing json element that can be either Array or Object at different times

Tags: android, json

Json that is returned by server has an element that is sometimes an empty array and other times an object. 
I wrote custom TypeAdapterFactory to best of my knowledge:

```
@Override
public T read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
    }
}
```

But it still throws: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 652 path $.timetable`

This is my Timetable class:

```
public final class Timetable implements Serializable{

private final Map<Integer, String> teachers;
private final Map<Integer, String> hours;
private final Map<Integer, String> rooms;
private final Map<Integer, String> groups;
private final Map<Integer, String> subjects;
private final Map<Integer, List<Map<String, String>>> entries;
}
```

So sometimes when timetable is empty json looks like this: `"timetable": []`
When it is not empty it is like this:

```
 "timetable": {
    "teachers": {
        "762": "sfsdfsdf",

    },
    "hours": {
        "1": "09:00",
    },
    "rooms": {
        "439": "sdfsdfsdf",
    },
    "subjects": {
        "738": "sdfsdfdsf",
    },
    "entries": {
        "10": [
            {
                "week": "1",
                "day": "6",
                "date": "2017-03-01",
                "hour": "1",
                "type": "0",
                "course": "3844",
                "teacher": "59502",
                "room": "640",
                "p": "-1",
                "table": "1447"
            },
            {
                "week": "1",
                "day": "6",
                "date": "2017-03-01",
                "hour": "2",
                "type": "0",
                "course": "4047",
                "teacher": "50792",
                "room": "799",
                "p": "-1",
                "table": "1447"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: `timetable` is JSONObject instead of JSONArray

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote, when timetable is empty it returned as Array when it is not empty it is returned as Object. So I need a way to be able to deserizlize it depending on the returned type.

Comment: I had a similar issue and resorted to make ``timetable`` a ``JsonElement`` which ``gson`` managed to deserialise without a problem. The issue is that then I had to manually figure out if ``timetable`` was an array or a json object. Luckily I had a simpler json than yours. Not sure if this is the best approach for you, but worth a thought I guess...

Comment: @Fred I am not sure if this is the best way, but it is a way. Great idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem similar to yours (I was getting an empty string when the array had no elements) so i created a generic GsonArrayDeserializer, this modified version for an Ojbect sould work for you

```
public class GsonObjectDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T result = null;
    if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        result = gson.fromJson(json.getAsJsonObject(), typeOfT);
    }

}
```

}

And using it like this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapter(Timetable.class , new GsonObjectDeserializer<Timetable>(Timetable.class))
.create();
```

EXTRA:

To use it with Retrofit2 add it like this

```
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.URL_BASE)
                ...... //other paramaeters
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

It's well explained [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter)

Comment: How would I apply it to Retrofit 2?

Comment: Great. Works like a charm! Thank you.